Can urine damage unfinished stucco
My home is under renovations and I just had the stucco redone. It hasn't been painted yet. I caught one of my neighbors peeing on the stucco on camera. Obliviously, I'm going to go talk to him about this, but should I be concerned of damage? I need to decide if I should bring up the potential stucco damage during the conversation.

If left to dry there should be no issues.  I would tell the neighbor that there could be damage to his wallet for urinating in  public if you show the police the video.
